# How to show field from a list in OOB approval workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, approval

I have made a copy of OOB approval workflow in SPD and using this workflow on a list.

I can display "Title" of item from that list in approval form (where it shows Approve, Reject, Request Change buttons).

But how do I display another field from that list called "SerialNo". I tried but it always displays as empty.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way to do this. One workaround is by the use of ID field and making a data connection back to the list. Then fetch the list item and display it in the form.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b5cf0d95-bd8e-47c9-89e4-56869a48c780/show-current-item-field-information-on-workflow-initiation-form?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

1. Open the workflow in SharePoint Designer .
2. Add initiation form parameters to the workflow .Give the parameter the same name as the columns in the list .Remember to add a parameter called ID .
3. Open the initiation form in InfoPath .Add a data connection to receive data from the list .
4. Add a rule on the ID field .Choose the action as ‘Set a field’s value’ .
5. Set an initiation parameter  such as Title to get the value from the Title column in  list data connection .
6. Add a filter on the Title column :ID(main data connection ) equals ID (list data connection ) .
7. In this way , the current item field will show up after you fill in the ID column on the initiation form .The ID column is shown in the URL when you start the workflow in IE .